# Checkbox entity field type return empty value

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, checkbox, entity

I have a form which list the possible answers of a quiz into a choice field (checkboxes)

Problem is when i check some boxes and submit my form i get an empty result instead of get checkboxes values...

Here is my form type :

```
namespace MyApp\QuizzBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class QuizzType extends AbstractType
{

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {

$builder
  ->add('reponses', 'entity', array(
        'class'=>'QuizzBundle:Reponses',
        'property'=>'titre',
        'multiple'=>true,
        'expanded'=>true,
        'required'=>true
  ))
;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
     $resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class'=>'MyApp\QuizzBundle\Entity\Quizz'
));
}

public function getName()
{
   return 'myapp_quizztype';
}
}
```

But if i try without     'enabled'=>true    i can choice multiple answers too and i can get their values in my controller...

Someone can help me ?

Comment: How are you trying to access the values in the controller?

Comment: I tried with `$request->request->get('myapp_quizztype');` and `$form->getData();` but both doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

so you've mapped an entity to your form, as a result, $form->getData() will be null.  If your quizz entity has a field named 'responses' (the same name as your form's field) you will find your data in the entity you passed in when creating the form.

```
$form = $this->createForm(new QuizzType(), $quiz);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $selected = $quiz->getResponses();  //you will find the selected responses this way.
}
```

Comment: Actually it doesnt work... I tried your method but i got an empty result again. I can show you my entities, my complete form type and my controller if it can help you. I have a OneToMany $reponses in my Quizz entity and a ManyToOne $quizz in my Reponses entity